# Main monitor screen tears, but only when secondary is rotated

Tags: nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, xorg, tearing

Kubuntu, Nvidia GPU, 515 Proprietary Driver. This seems to be a prevalent problem across the years but I haven't found any semblance of a solution anywhere across the internet.
If I start a game, even with VSync, I get terrible screen tearing constantly as long as my secondary monitor is set to portrait orientation. If I set it to landscape, the tears lessen significantly, then stop entirely after a minute or so.

The three most common suggestions seem to be keeping my compositor enabled (causes stuttering and general bad performance in games), enable "Force Composition Pipeline" through Nvidia settings (same as previous) or to just move straight to Wayland. (Already tried, Nvidia + KDE do not work well and my entire desktop was unusably broken).

The best workaround I have so far is to automatically rotate my secondary monitor to portrait mode again with Gamemode automatically running xrandr commands. But that isn't ideal, as that then makes it difficult to read anything I have on said monitor.

Any other suggestions on what I could try to alleviate this strange problem?

Operating System: Kubuntu 22.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.25.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.98.0
Qt Version: 5.15.3
Kernel Version: 5.15.0-47-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 6 × Intel® Core™ i5-8600K CPU @ 3.60GHz
Memory: 15.6 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080/PCIe/SSE2
Manufacturer: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd.
Product Name: MS-7B61
System Version: 1.0

Comment: welcome to askubuntu so a lot of the time you will be asked for more info so that we can help better this is one of thos times. In the system settings there is about this system and in there is copy to clipboard click on that and edit it in.

Comment: also can you add screen shots to your question

Comment: System specs have been added. What do you need screenshots of?

Comment: of the screen taring